# Use variable after loop in Python [selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am trying to print `quallity` or any variable after the loop but it's not working.  It's working before the loops only. How can I use it?
I want to send get request with all this details to link.

```js
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for x in range(1, 2):
    driver.get("http://sparo.live/movies?page=%d" % (x))
    text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxALL']/article/a" )
    print (len(text))
    array = []
    info = []
    for link in text:
        links = link.get_attribute("href")
        array.append(links)

    for i in array:    
        driver.get(i)
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/h1")
        english_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/h2")
        year = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")
        geners = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/span[1]")
        description = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[5]/div[9]/p")
        preimg = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/img")
        img = preimg.get_attribute("src")
        quallity = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-content1']/div/div[3]/a/div[1]/p[2]")
        pretrailer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[6]/ul/li/iframe")
        trailer = pretrailer.get_attribute("src")
        prelinks = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-content1']/div/div[3]/a")
        watchonclick = prelinks.get_attribute("onclick")
        watchlink = watchonclick.replace('open', 'location.replace')
        driver.execute_script(watchlink)
        find_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='box']/div[2]/a" )
        for div in find_div:
            links_to_watch = div.get_attribute("href")
            break
        print ("quallity: '%s'." % quallity.text)
```

Comment: Surely if the code ever enters the inner loop, `quallity` gets printed and you are free to use it after the loop(s). If you aren't, then it's because `array` has length `0` every single time, which can only be due to `text` being similarly having length `0`. Try printing out these variables and see if you find something other than what you expect.

Comment: I guess you're the big fan of `for` loops :) What is the point of `for x in range(1, 2)`? And what is the point of breaking loop after first iteration (in `for div in find_div`)?

Comment: @Andersson I am learning its my first script, range1,2 need to go from page X TO Y but i am debugging so its only 1 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the result somewhere if you want to print that outside of loop:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

quality=[] #edited line

for x in range(1, 2):
    driver.get("http://sparo.live/movies?page=%d" % (x))
    text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxALL']/article/a" )
    print (len(text))
    array = []
    info = []
    for link in text:
        links = link.get_attribute("href")
        array.append(links)

    for i in array:
        driver.get(i)
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/h1")
        english_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/h2")
        year = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")
        geners = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/span[1]")
        description = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[5]/div[9]/p")
        preimg = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/img")
        img = preimg.get_attribute("src")
        quallity = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-content1']/div/div[3]/a/div[1]/p[2]")
        quality.append(quallity.text)     #edited line
        pretrailer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div/div/div[6]/ul/li/iframe")
        trailer = pretrailer.get_attribute("src")
        prelinks = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tab-content1']/div/div[3]/a")
        watchonclick = prelinks.get_attribute("onclick")
        watchlink = watchonclick.replace('open', 'location.replace')
        driver.execute_script(watchlink)
        find_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='box']/div[2]/a" )
        for div in find_div:
            links_to_watch = div.get_attribute("href")
            break
        for quality_type in quality:
            print(quality_type)
```

output:

```
HD
HD
HD
HD
HD
HD
HD
HD
HD
BDRip
```

Comment: It's important to note that retrieving the text of the element inside the loop is what makes this work. If you instead did `quality.append(quallity)` you could not later do for `q in qaulity:print(q.text)`. The reason for this is Selenium doesn't fetch the data from the page until it is requested. That means the element is no longer valid when a new page is navigated to or something else makes the DOM change. The OP's code loads a page each loop so holding the references to elements won't work